# .NET Core 2.1 -> 3.1 migration web API no longer loads

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I followed some guides on migrating a .NET Core 2.1 project to the 3.1 LTS. Now whenever I try to debug, the web api will no longer start up in IIS Express. Below is my code before and after of the Startup.cs and Program.cs. It is tested on a windows machine but hosted on a Linux machine with Apache using a reverse proxy. I had also tried deploying the api to Linux and it works, with the exception of one of my methods that now returns a 500 error.

**Program.cs for 2.1**

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

**Program.cs for 3.1**

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {

            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

**Startup.cs for 2.1**

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSingleton<HttpHelper, HttpHelper>();
        services.AddSingleton<MemoryCacheClass>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Main" });
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs for 3.1**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSingleton<HttpHelper, HttpHelper>();
        services.AddSingleton<MemoryCacheClass>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Configure IIS to use failed request tracing and/or consult the event viewer to actually get details on the error that's occurring. Just a 500 is not particularly informative. (Configuring logging for your own code is also a good idea, of course, but not all errors can be captured that way if there is a more basic configuration/activation problem.)

Comment: Jeroen, I had gone into the Event Viewer and saw nothing for IIS Express. I then went into the IIS Express (%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\) logs and trace logs and also saw nothing regarding the web api project at all. I definitely agree that logging is needed at the code level.